# How generated Ruby Wash_Out WebService Stub from WSDL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services

Is there any way to generate API and controller code stub from existing WSDL file when using wash_out in ruby on rails ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was discussed in wash_out's [Github issues page](https://github.com/inossidabile/wash_out/issues/57).

The response was that it would not work to the degree that it would be useful.